# Twitter API V2 media upload causes 400 Bad Request

Tags: node.js, twitter, axios

I try to upload an image to the Twitter API but whatever I try, I get a 400 Bad Request error.

Code that should work based on most examples I found online.

```
        const encodedImage = fs.readFileSync("/tmp/image.jpg", {
          encoding: "base64",
        });
        const {
          data: { media_id },
        } = await axios.post(
          "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json",
          {
            media_data: encodedImage,
            media_category: "tweet_image",
          },
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: authHeaderMedia["Authorization"],
              "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
            },
          }
        );
```

I am trying to upload the image to the API but I always get the bad request error.

Comment: Try changing your content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as far as I understand `multipart/form-data` will only work if you give twitter the raw binary of the file. In HTTP the content parts are transmitted differently as opposed to just a forward XHR request

Comment: The solution was to add the data as FormData to the body not as a JSON object and on top using the content type `multipart/form-data`

Comment: did you upload using oAuth 2 Credentials?

Answer (score 0):

When reading the image file encoded in base64, utilize the media_data parameter while passing the arguments through a FormData() object. Ensure to set the 'Content-Type' as 'multipart/form-data' for proper handling. Consider the following code snippet as an example [here](https://gist.github.com/mayankmtg/5f99463a8f7f90428eaaf0cc8bf2deab)